# Thingsboard - release-3.3 compile problem

Tags: java, compilation, iot, thingsboard

I'm unable to compile release-3.3 on Ubuntu-20.04 -- I get the error noted below.  I followed  the instructions noted on the Thingsboard website; downloaded 'release-3.3' source from git and then ran 'mvn clean install'.  Am I doing something wrong ??  Can I skip over this step (not interested in Edge anyway).

```
    Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
2021-09-12 20:54:53,796 [main] ERROR o.t.s.s.edge.rpc.EdgeGrpcService - Failed to start Edge RPC server!
java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:7070
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServer.start(NettyServer.java:328)
        at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:179)
        at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:90)
..[skip over many statements similar to above]..
Caused by: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: bind(..) failed: Address already in use
2021-09-12 20:54:53,796 [main] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'edgeGrpcService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'edgeGrpcService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start Edge RPC server!
2021-09-12 20:54:53,813 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'edgeGrpcService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'edgeGrpcService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start Edge RPC server!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
```

Comment: This should be posted as question on the [thingsboard github issue page](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues). --- From what I see, i would assume that those are integration tests and java reports that the port (`7070`) is already in use. Either disable the tests (`mvn -DskipTests clean install`) or stop whatever is running on port `7070`.

Comment: #1 Also you can create the issue as @Turing85 said referencing to this question. #2 What is your o.s ?

Comment: I added a [bug report](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/5234) - looks like port 7070 is being used by another application (anydesk).  Would be nice, per the bug report, if all those -D options are documented/listed somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is: **Address already in use**

Reviewing your log, you can see **0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:7070**

To void the same error, try to identify what other application are running at 7070 and kill them. Sometimes is due to previous failed attempts. You only need to list the process and its ports. After that, identify its pid and kill.

### Linux sample:

```
netstat -tulpn
```

[image]

Search the 7070 port and locate its PID to kill it

```
kill -9 6185
```